# Wix's react-native-navigation, drawer and overlay

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using the [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) and this their github politic is to [forward all questions about their lib on stackoverflow](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/6656), I'm asking the question here.

So here is the issue I'm having:

My app has a left drawer and an overlay.

On Android (did not test yet on iOS), if I open the left drawer, the overlay that was already open before is rendered over the drawer that opens.

How can I have the drawer to be rendered over the overlay?

### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

1 - SetRoot with a left drawer.

2 - right after setRoot, show an overlay

3 - when using your app, open the drawer. The overlay is rendered over the drawer on Android. I would like the contrary.

### Environment

React Native Navigation version: 7.1.0

React Native version: 0.63.3

Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): tested on android

Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): device and simulator, Android 10

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the rnn will be updgraded to address this issue: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/6656